# argmin() в Java

Tags: java, java-8

Существуют стандартные методы получения `min()`, `max()`, `argmin()` и `argmax()` почти в любом языке. Есть ли такие в Java?

например у менять есть массив `m=[5,6,3,0,3,23,13]`. и я хочу сделать `m.argmin()` и получить `3` (3 - номер позиции в m на которой стоит минимальное значение: 0)

Comment: Вот https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/math/ArrayMath.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Integer[] array = new Integer[]{5, 6, 3, 0, 3, 23, 13};

    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);

    Integer minimum = Collections.min(list);
    Integer maximum = Collections.max(list);

    int minArg = list.indexOf(minimum);
    int maxArg = list.indexOf(maximum);

    System.out.println("Minimum value " + minimum + " at position " + minArg); // Minimum value 0 at position 3
    System.out.println("Maximum value " + maximum + " at position " + maxArg); // Maximum value 23 at position 5
```